# Add existing live template file to pycharm 2020.1?

Tags: pycharm, odoo

You can add existing live template file to pycharm 2020.1 just :

1. go to this location:  ~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1
2. create new folder named : templates
3. put you file inside this folder
4. restart pycharm

Thanks.

this link to odoo template: https://gitlab.com/mramadan2711/odoo-auto-complate-template.git

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and found that there is one simplest way to insert PyCharm live templates dependless of the operating system or PyCharm version, as described 
[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62061638/12647106)